# C# inheritance in <T>

Tags: c#, inheritance

ow to indicate that T is inherited from other class that implements certain methods:

```
public Class A
 {
    public string GetAccessPoint();
    public string GetPriorityMap();
 }

public Class IndexBuilder<T> where T : A
{
   List<string> Go<T>(T obj)
   {
      string aPt=obj.GetAccessPoint();
      string pMap=obj.GetPriorityMap();
   }
}
```

In other words, I cannot access GetAccessPoint and GetPriority map of the obj although I indicated that it is inherited from A.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using generics for `IndexBuilder` at all?

Comment: yes, because instead of T obj, it's List<T> obj and that list must be indexed (in a certain way) for different types T

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you redefined what T is when you made the Go method generic.  Since T is defined at the class level, there is no need to redefine it in Go.  Try this:

```
public Class IndexBuilder<T> where T : A
{
   List<string> Go(T obj)
   {
      string aPt=obj.GetAccessPoint();
      string pMap=obj.GetPriorityMap();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying an extra `<T>` in `List<string> Go<T>(T obj)`, which redefines `T` to a different type that does not necessarily inherit from `A`. Use `List<string> Go(T obj)` instead to avoid redefining `T`.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained (correctly) by other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802508/65358), the issue is that you're defining a new `<T>` in your method.

That being said, if this is the entirety of your class, you may not need a generic class anyways.  The following would work fine:

```
public Class IndexBuilder
{
   List<string> Go(A obj)
   {
      string aPt=obj.GetAccessPoint();
      string pMap=obj.GetPriorityMap();
      // Create list...
   }
}
```

If you're just using instances of `A` directly, there is no need for generics in `IndexBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding T in class with T in `Go` method.